# Wordpress – search not working after permalink change to postname

Tags: wordpress, search, permalinks

I have a multiple dropdown search bar on my website that no longer works after I changed the permalink structure to postname.

Example query that would be created by search would be:

```
/?cat=1&m=201505&author=5&tag=blue
```

However, I just get a Error 403 now when I attempt to search.

Would greatly appreciate anyone's help or advice, many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tydy up Nathaniel :)

Comment: Just to add, searches work if i do individual searches, but not if they are a combined query;


Example
/?cat=1  
/?m=201505  
/?author=5  
/?tag=blue

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a simple fix that allows passing the query, even if permalinks  is set as postname.

Simply add 's=&' to the start of a query, in the form it just needs to be added as a hidden field at the start below the form declaration.